# html5 input type file accept image/* - where stores the image?

Tags: html

I'm using html5

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" accept="image/*" capture>
  <input type="submit" value="Carica">
</form>
```

in a web page accessible by mobiles for upload a picture taken "at the moment" with the phone. The file upload.php is this:

```
<?php
$target_dir = "file_upl/";
$target_file = $target_dir . "nomeFile.jpg";
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
    echo "The file has been uploaded.";
} else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
}
?>
```

No problem with the code, I find the image in the right folder (I know that the name is always the same *nomeFile.jpg*, no problem for this), my question is: with this HTML code the phone takes a picture which will be uploaded, but after the upload what happens to the file of the picture in the phone? I need that the phone deletes the file after the upload (I don't want to leave hundred of unused pictures files in the phones that use the web page), is the file automatically deleted after the upload? If not, how can I force to delete the file in the phone after the upload?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is the file automatically deleted after the upload?

That's an implementation detail of the phone.

> If not, how can I force to delete the file in the phone after the upload?

You have no control over what the browser does with the image after it is sent it to the server.

Comment: It depends on the phone OS or the browser? And where should I find this specifications eventually?

Comment: Both: The OS provides APIs that let the browser access the camera (and which may automatically save pictures taken, not save it at all, or give the browser the choice) then the browser author decides how to use it. The specifications will be the API documentation for whichever OS you're interested in.